# Drawing convexity polygon in Pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

Is it possible to draw convexity polygon with Pyglet?
If yes, how can I draw it? I only know n vertex and their 2D coordinates.

Comment: I have posted an answer. While you check it and post feedback, it would be good that you post here the code that you used to successfully draw n vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the primitive `GL_POLYGON` (or even try `GL_LINE_LOOP`).

Check documentation...

https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/pyglet.graphics.html

http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/graphics.html

... and an example

[Pyglet GL_QUADS and GL_POLYGON not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628870/pyglet-gl-quads-and-gl-polygon-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cou can do it.
Just take the following code snippets to get a feeling for the functionality.
Play a little bit with the modes:
GL_POLYGON,
GL_TRIANGLES,
GL_TRIANGLE_FAN and
GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP.

Left mouse click button increases points in window. First drawing is shown after clicking three times. Del-Button clears the window.

GL_POLYGON and GL_TRIANGLE_FAN behave in the same way, the first point is the anchor point of the convex polygon and is used for every drawn triangle from the points list.

GL_TRIANGLE takes 3 points for drawing a triangle, then the next 3 points and so on.

With GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP you can draw every complex structure. But there you have be careful for the given points. Sometimes, you have to visit a point more than one time.
The first triangle is drawn by points 1-3.
The second triangle is drawn by points 2-4, then 3-5, 4-6 and so on.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key

global n
global vertices
global colors
window = pyglet.window.Window()
n = 0
vertices = []
colors = []
polygon = None
main_Batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    main_Batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
    if n > 2:
        polygon = main_Batch.add(n, pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON, None,
                                         ('v2i', vertices),
                                         ('c3B', colors))
    main_Batch.draw()


@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.DELETE:
        global n;
        global vertices
        global colors
        vertices = []
        colors = []
        n = 0


@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    if button == pyglet.window.mouse.LEFT:
        global n
        vertices.append(x)
        vertices.append(y)
        n = n + 1
        colors.append(255)
        colors.append(255)
        colors.append(255)

pyglet.app.run()
```